# Select records by area and update value of CSV

Tags: qgis, python, csv, mapbox

In my little project I have a CSV with more rows than I can count, and I am trying to find a tool that can do the following:

1. Plot each record on a map using their lat lon coordinates, interactively so a mouse hover can display some metadata.
2. Each marker is coloured based on the categorical value of one of the columns.
3. Be able select a subset by area (such as in QGIS), and change their categorical value.
4. Save these changes back into the original CSV.

I have been able to achieve 1 and 2 with Mapbox in Python/plotly (I know 3 is possible if I do it in JavaScript). I was wondering if there are easier way to do this.

Comment: How big is your data? You can do everything is QGIS. 1. Import delimited text layer + Display : https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#display-properties 2. Symbology > Categorized 3. you can it already 4. What kind of changes do you mean exactly ?

Comment: do you need to use QGIS? i suggest you to use Appsheet extension of Google sheets

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention that I have also explored with QGIS, and for to step 2.5. My dataset is huge (100K+ records) and I need to update the categorical values in batches, which I could not figure out how to do in QGIS. Any further ideas? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

All of this can be achieved using QGIS. A very simple example below:

Sample data

[image: Sample Data]

1a. `Layer` > `Data Source Manager` > `Delimited Text`. Select your csv file and ensure all the settings are appropriate (File Format, Header lines etc). Define your point coordinates using the lat lon coordinates in your data.
[image: Data Source Manager]

1b. Save your layer as a Geopackage or similar. This will allow it to be edited.
[image: Save Geopackage]

2. Define symbology within the `Layer Properties`.
   [image: Symbology]
3. Select a subset of your data (manually or using an SQL). Then edit the category as required ([Field Calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html?highlight=field%20calculator#using-the-field-calculator)) can be useful here.
   [image: Subset]
   [image]
4. Export your updated Geopackage layer to CSV. You can either create a new CSV, or overwrite the original file.

[image: Save to CSV]

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer. I forgot to mention that I also explored down this path, and got stuck when I tried to edit the field for multiple records simultaneously. The `Toggle multi edit mode` button in the attribute table window is always greyed out, like in your 5th picture. Any fuirther ideas? Cheers

Comment: You need to `Toggle editing mode` first, then the `Toggle multi edit mode` button will not be greyed out. Have a look at the [Editing attribute values](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html?highlight=attribute#editing-attribute-values) documentation. 
Also for reference, you can edit an attribute for multiple features at the same time without Multi edit mode. Multi edit mode allows you to edit multiple attributes simultaneously.